# REST API - PHP - Salesforce- Update Account owner byName

Tags: rest-api, php

The following code updates the account name and the billingcity, is there a way to update the account owner

```
    function update_account($id, $revenue, $instance_url, $access_token) {
        $url = "$instance_url/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/$id";

       $content = json_encode(array("Name" => $new_name, "BillingCity" => $city));


        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token",
                "Content-type: application/json"));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

        curl_exec($curl);

        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ($status != 204) {
            die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
        }

        echo "HTTP status $status updating account \n";

        curl_close($curl);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you know new `OwnerId`, just assign it to new variable `$someOwnerId` and put as key to map.

```
$content = json_encode(array("Name" => $new_name, "BillingCity" => $city, "OwnerId" => $someOwnerId));
```

Comment: I do not know the owner id, is it possible to update by owner name?

Comment: No, you need to know salesforce Id to perform update

Comment: ok ownerid==userid, yes?

Comment: @user580950 yes. here is a https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm example , that could help you